# Is "Razor Crest" the name or the model of the Mandalorian's ship?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the first episode of *The Mandalorian*, the Mythrol appraises the Mandalorian's ship:

> **Mythrol**: I like your ship. She's a classic. // Razor Crest, am I right? Pre-Empire? // I have a lot of credits, by the way. That's why I offered to hail a Cruiser. [(transcript source)](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_1:_The_Mandalorian)

There's no indication that he knows who the Mandalorian is or has heard of his ship before, but he identifies it as "Razor Crest, am I right?" implying that it's a type of ship. Similarly, in Chapter 6: The Prisoner, Mayfeld makes another comment about it connecting "Razor Crest" with the ship's age:

> **Mayfeld**: Razor Crest? I can't believe that thing can fly. Looks like a Canto Bight slot machine. [(transcript source)](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_6:_The_Prisoner)

However, the same episode and some official tie-in material seems to use "The Razor Crest" as the ship's name:

> **Zero**: The Razor Crest is scrambling our signature, and I'm inside the prison system. It's impressive that this gunship has survived the Empire without being impounded.
> [(transcript source)](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_6:_The_Prisoner)

> Razor Crest
>
> A former military craft used to patrol local territories in the time before the Empire, the Razor Crest is the Mandalorian's trusty transport and living quarters, as he scours the Outer Rim for fugitives to catch. [(starwars.com databank entry)](https://www.starwars.com/databank/razor-crest)

The Lego model italicizes it on the box as well:

[image: Part of a picture of a Lego box showing that "Razor Crest" is italicized]

Is there an official source that clarifies this one way or the other? To me it seems most likely that the ship wasn't supposed to have a name and that the characters are referring to it as "The Razor Crest" the way that people in real life might refer to "the Winnebago" or "the 737", but it's also unusual for a Star Wars ship to have no name, especially one that receives so much focus throughout the series.

Comment: In the same episode w/ Mayfeld (The Prisoner), Ran also says: "Well, the Crest is the only reason I let you back in here."

Comment: The Mando has a name but everyone calls him the Mando... could be the same with his ship, makes sense - a mando would likely see a ship as nothing more than a tool, wouldn't bother naming it and just call it by it's factory designation which may be 'Razor Crest'

Comment: Maybe you found an oversight by the scriptwriters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the powers-that-be can't make up their minds - in The Book of Boba Fett chapter 5 "a Razor Crest" is spoken by multiple people as a type rather than a specific ship.

The traffic cop refers to it as "a Razor Crest". In this context, "a" makes sense as a model rather than a specific ship.
[image: Did you used to fly a Razor Crest?]

Mando's discussion with Peli Motto also repeatedly refers to "a Razor Crest" and never says "the Razor Crest". While a few instances could refer to a ship like Mando's Razor Crest, Peli Motto explicitly contrasts that meaning with it as a model.

"I never said I had a Razor Crest, I said I had a replacement Razor Crest"
[image]
[image]

Her reference to "*some* plain old Razor Crest" also makes more sense as a model than as a specific ship.

[image: some plain old Razor Crest]

Comment: Nice job coming back and updating with a new answer based on further developments!

Answer (score 7):

### Update 2021-09-15: It's the name

According to a [tweet](https://twitter.com/atomicmassgames/status/1436133586235760646) from Atomic Mass Games announcing a Razor Crest expansion to the X-wing Miniatures Game, the Razor Crest is an "ST-70 Assault Ship":

[image: Image of a game card for the Razor Crest]

### Original answer:

A recent update to *Star Wars: Squadrons* added a Razor Crest model to go on the player's dashboard:

[image: Screenshot of Star Wars: Squadrons]
([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-hS7VQspWI))

The in-game description reads:

> Razor Crest Gunship
>
> LEGENDARY
>
> Both Imperial and New Republic pilots are wary of these pre-Empire military gunships, as their outdated design only makes them more unpredictable.

As far as I know, this is the only source so far to explicitly describe the ship's model outside the context of the particular ship seen in the show. The game takes place about four years before *The Mandalorian*, so it's unlikely that this is meant to depict Din Djarin's particular ship in-universe, and the description says "these pre-Empire military gunships", implying that "Razor Crest" is a type of gunship.

Furthermore, in Season 2, Episode 4 of *The Mandalorian*, "Chapter 12: The Siege":

> New Republic captain Carson Teva interviews Greef Karga about the events of the episode, and asks about the Mandalorian's ship in an attempt to trick Karga into telling the truth about what happened, but Karga demurs:
>
>  *TEVA: How long after the Razor Crest jumped out...*
>
>  *KARGA: (scoffs) I never said anything about a Razor Crest.*
>
>  The fact that it's referred to as "a" Razor Crest indicates that it's a ship class.

Comment: don't forget Mythrol's statement in episode 1, ambiguous though it is: "Mythrol: I like your ship. She's a classic. Razor Crest, am I right? Pre-Empire?"

Comment: @NKCampbell Yeah, I guess I should say it's the only source to talk about the model outside the context of Din's ship. The game text is ambiguous enough (it wouldn't be completely out of the question to say something like "Millennium Falcon Freighter / These pre-Empire freighters...") that I'm reluctant to accept my own answer, but it's at least a data point.

Comment: This oughta be the approved answer.

Comment: That tweet is not conclusive at all.   It is common for models of aircraft to have a model number and also a "nickname".   For example [Lockheed P-38 Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-38_Lightning).   That is just one of dozens of examples.   The fact that its official designation is "ST-70 Assault Ship" doesn't mean "Razorcrest" can't be the model's nickname.

Answer (score 7):

### We have multiple canon sources confirming that the name of the ship is the *Razor Crest* (e.g. rather than that it's a Razor Crest-class ship).

[*The Star Wars Book*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Book) states that the ship is ***named*** the Razor Crest. There doesn't seem to be any room for ambiguity here.

> When not flitting from world to world in his gunship, the *Razor Crest*, Mando visits a Mandalorian covert hidden in the sewers of Nevarro.
>
> [and]
>
> The Mandalorian at the helm of the *Razor Crest*, an antiquated gunship that serves him well.

Note that **the italicisation indicates that this is a ship's name not a model**, since models are always in roman fonts and ship names are always in *italics*, e.g.

> Darth Vader’s Star Destroyer, the *Devastator*, arrives to face the rebel fleet.

---

The canon factbook [*The Mandalorian Handbook*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Mandalorian_Handbook) outright states that the ship is **named** the *Razor Crest*.

> The Mandalorian flies a battered old gunship named the *Razor Crest*
> around the galaxy. It is equipped with a range of gear that helps him
> work as a bounty hunter. The ship even has a carbon-freezing chamber
> that he uses to put his targets in stasis so they are easier to
> transport.

---

The Young Reader book [*The Mandalorian: A Clan of Two*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian:_A_Clan_of_Two) say much the same, that his ship is called the *Razor Crest*.

> The Mandalorian was a bounty hunter.
>
> It was his job to capture whoever, or whatever, someone hired him to find. **He flew a ship called the *Razor Crest*.**

---

Series creator Jon Favreua confirmed in a recent panel that the ship is called the Razor Crest.

> ***"The name of the ship is the Razor Crest,** that the Mandalorian flies around in."*

---

As to how *Mythrol knew the name of the ship* (e.g. having just seen it from the outside for a few seconds) it's worthy of note that the [original concept artwork](https://youtu.be/8YuaIwVbEZo?t=89) for the ship had **conspicuous writing on the side** that doesn't correspond to classic [Aurabesh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurebesh). It's possible that this is the name of the ship in some script that he's familiar with.

At some point in the design process the writing was scrubbed from the side of the ship, but this may have happened quite late on and never got caught when the dialogue was finalised.

[image]

Comment: Could it be both? I think both the answers here have sources pointing to it with reasonable amounts of proof. Like the Mando is called The Mandalorian but there are clearly other Mandalorians?

Comment: I agree with Wraith Leader. There are many Nimitz class aircraft carriers but CVN-68 is named the *Nimitz*. In contrast if I was to go out for a drive I might say "I'm taking the Honda" I have not named my vehicles so their names by default are the *Honda* and the *Jeep*

Comment: @WraithLeader - I see no good evidence that it's a *Razor Crest Model Gunship*. The evidence from the other sources (a semi-canon video game and an easily misunderstood conversation) don't seem solid.

Comment: How would Mythrol know the name of the ship having never met Mando before?

Comment: @Skooba - That is an excellent second question.

Comment: People can keep downvoting, but the evidence is piling up that it's called the Razor Crest, including **from the guy who made the show**.

Comment: @Skooba If years of editing Wookieepedia have taught me anything, it's that Star Wars canon is unhampered by storytelling logic. I agree that this doesn't make sense from the perspective of the show's dialogue, and hope that the eventual Visual Guide explains it (possibly with the "both" answer), but in the meantime, hats off to Valorum for finding multiple canon sources, let alone a side comment by John Favreau in an hour-long video.

Comment: Does the new answer sourced from S01E05 of the Book of Boba Fett change your mind?

Comment: @Skooba - I think that Mando is the kind of person who names his dog 'dog'.

Comment: To backup @Valorum's point about Mando's logic with naming.  He never gave Grogu a name.  There was a season a and a half before he learned the actual name.  But rather than giving him a name as most adoptive parents would do, he just kept calling him "Kid".